# Have there been any lawsuits over gerrymandering outside the United States?

Tags: political-history, election, maps, electoral-system

In countries that use [first-past-the-post legislative elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting), drawing district maps that have political effects is called [Gerrymandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering). It is famously seen as shameless but nearly impossible to prevent. In the lawsuit-happy United States of America, lawsuits over redistricting (delimitation) have gone to the Supreme Court repeatedly.

India, the United Kingdom, Canada, Pakistan, and Malaysia also use first-past-the-post and also hear complaints about their district maps (several examples are given in *Delimitation in India* by Alistair McMillan). However, **have these concerns been litigated outside of the United States?** Cursory searching suggests not, but surely some disenfranchised minorities in those countries have also sued for redress?

[image]

Comment: The U.S. is ***not*** a *Westminster-type legislature* ("*Aspects of the Westminster system of government include an executive branch made up of members of the legislature, and that is responsible to the legislature; ....*") but a *constitutional republic. It has no *parliament*, and the executive is a separate branch of government from the legislature. You are conflating it with *first-past-the-post* elections. As Canada is discovering, a written constitution is incompatible with a Westminster legislature.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - While true, for the purposes of this question the two are comparable. Both legislative bodies rely on district representation, rather than nationwide proportional representation. Do you have a suggestion for a way the question could be phrased that would be more technically accurate?

Comment: @T.E.D.: The question must remove all references to *Westminster-type legislatures*, as that option is completely orthogonal to having *first-past-the-post* elections for legislative representatives.  How the Executive relates to the Legislature, and in particular whether it is subordinate to or independent of the Legislature, is completely irrelevant in a discussion of how Legislative representatives are elected.

Comment: @Pieter This question is not at all about the executive, solely about the FPTP elected legislature, and the heritage of that mechanism is definitely the Westminster style. The U.S., Canada, and the rest all inherited their district-based legislative electoral systems directly from the U.K. To quote Wikipedia: "Traditionally, the lower house is elected using first-past-the-post from single-member districts".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I'm more interested in what would be better, rather than even more details about what is currently wrong.

Comment: I have edited to redirect attention away from the term "Westminster".